# Hardware video acceleration in VLC

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, video, intel-graphics, vlc

I have not been able to get VLC to use VA-API on my machine and it's driving me insane!

I'm running Arch Linux on a ASUS ZenBook UX305CA with Integrated Intel HD Graphics 515. I have installed `libva-intel-driver-1.8.3-1` and `vlc-2.2.6-2`.

When I run `vainfo` I get:

```
libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: User requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_40
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.40 (libva )
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Skylake - 1.8.3
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
```

Also direct rendering is on:

```
glxinfo | grep "direct rendering"
direct rendering: Yes
```

Everything seems fine, but for some reason VLC does not provide the same results (I have `VA-API video decoder via DRM` selected in preferences):

```
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[000055f6e93dc148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with operation failed,driver_name=i965
[00007fa4280009c8] vaapi_drm generic error: Failed to initialize the VAAPI device
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007fa4280207c8] freetype spu text error: Breaking unbreakable line
```

If I set the driver (`export LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965`) before running VLC I get the following output:

```
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[000056014a004148] core libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 1
libva info: User requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_40
libva error: /usr/lib/dri/i965_drv_video.so init failed
libva info: va_openDriver() returns -1
[00007f08ac0009c8] vaapi_drm generic error: Failed to initialize the VAAPI device
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[00007f08ac008328] freetype spu text error: Breaking unbreakable line
```

Comment: What do you have Tools->Preferences->Video->Output set to? Try using OpenGL video output (experimental). This works for me. I think you need an OpenGL output method for Intel hardware acceleration on Linux, but I haven't been able to confirm this for sure.

Comment: I just tried using OpenGL output with no success :(